# pip install func for python will not work on my win system

Tags: python, pip

I was trying to develop a virtual machine for my friend, I decided to use python pip, but when I typed in install after pip (pip install wolframalpha), the "i" is highlighted as an "invalid syntax". I have tried capital "i" in install, but it still shows the error, I do believe I have searched for all possible reasons, but did not come to the one that is my reason for all my problems. also, i have tried python IDLE and the cmd prompt widows comes with, along with uninstalling and reinstall python 3.8.5, yet that did nothing. below is a screen shot of my problem.

[pip install error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B29aM.png)

Comment: That's because you are in the python shell. You need to be in a windows command prompt

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+SyntaxError

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are using python in your shell, instead what you want to do is open up command prompt and type pip install (your module), or if this throws you an error configure pip to your path variables than try again.

Comment: Thank you for your effort in helping me, however, the picture below is what I am encountering (except with "install wolframalpha"). 
       Here is the link to the picture that describes my problem: 
         https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAMpL.png

Comment: This just means you have not installed pip to your path or you have not installed pip to begin with